# Save button to close window after saving

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

For adding an item to list, the `newForm.aspx` is opened in new window. After clicking on save button I need to close the window.

I used `window.close(`), It just closes the window but the item is not saved. It means before saving only the window is closed. What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: You might use a modal dialog in stead of opening a new window:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Use "OpenPopUpPage(url to newform.aspx)" instead of window.open

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a solution which closes the new form once item is saved. Then SharePoint provides an OOB way to launch the new forms in a dialog, which will close the form once you save an item. But this is not set by default.

Follow steps to open form in dialog.

1. Go to list settings
2. Under general settings section, click on `Advanced Settings` link
3. Scroll down the window, and "Check" the second last option "Launch forms in dialog?" and save it.

[image]

**Update**:

If you want to open the list's new item form, from some other page on your SharePoint site. Then you can rely on `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);`, which opens the page in dialog.

```
function openInDailog() {
     var options = {
         url: '/Lists/YourListName/NewForm.aspx',
         tite: 'New Form',
         allowMaximize: false,
         showClose: true,
         width: 430,
         height: 230
     };

     SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);

     return false;
}
```

Refer [SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog for SP 2013](http://blog.solutions2share.net/2013/05/spuimodaldialogshowmodaldialog-do-not.html)

Comment: Is it possible to give a link for this so that clicking on link, that dialog should appear

Comment: Do you want this link to be on some other page? Which when clicked opens the dialog form?

Comment: yes on other page..

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can have a look..

Comment: I used the same code, the newForm opens as dialog but it is automatically getting closed

Comment: Did item not got saved?

Comment: the dialog box is opening and then closing automatically

Comment: You can debug the JavaScript and see what's going wrong. I suspect only a minor issue

Comment: can we write some code for that dialog..

Comment: You mean something of your own and not `SP UI`?

Comment: yes, there I have to populate some columns using rest

Comment: I am not exactly clear on what you ask for. You want to open List's NewForm in a dailog, but using your JavaScript and not of SharePoint's. And second thing is you want to execute some rest calls, is this rest code going to execute before you open Dailog? or on the NewForm?

Comment: after dialog is opened , that means newForm.aspx, there I need to write some code like jqeury or rest.

Comment: Writing JavaScript on NewForm is not straight forward. Only way is to add a content editor webpart on it.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog was automatically getting closed so I made some changes to the code provided by Asad then it worked..

```
<script>


function openModalDialog() {
         var options = {
             url: '/Lists/YourListName/NewForm.aspx',
             tite: 'Sample Title',
             allowMaximize: false,
             showClose: true,
             width: 980,
             args: {title: "title from arguments"},
             height: 400
         };        
         SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);        
         return false;
     }
</script>
```

And then adding code to this newform.aspx which is opened as dialog is same as adding to a normal newform.aspx page i.e. by adding a content editor page.